# Fixed div not moving in iphone

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css

I have a div (header) with the following css, when i opened my website in iphone and scrolls horizontally everything scrolls except the header, i need the header to be scrolled along with other contents.

This happens only in iphone, it's working fine in windows and android.

Thanks...

```
 .staticheader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
  top: 0px;
```

}

Comment: Please give the ios version.

Comment: checked in ios6 and ios7

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you use float: left?

Try

```
left: 0px;
```

instead of

```
float: left;
```

Comment: removed float left, still not moving

Comment: did you add 'left: 0px;'?